# Very basic question regarding "signing" your software

Tags: vsto, code-signing

I am writing some addins (VSTO) for excel, word and visio to be used by the people in my company. When visual studio compiles the code it also creates a file called XXX_temporaryKey.pfx. This key apparently expires in one year. Does that mean that my MSI installation files will no longer work after one year? Is there some way to get a permanent license without having to buy one? If it only  means that my users will be presented with the "do you trust this software" warning that's ok, they all know me and where I'm at.
In the visual studio "my project" tab, is it necessary to select the "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" checkbox? I am not publishing via visual studio's publishing feature but rather using Wix to create my MSI installers.
Yes I googled, there's a LOT of info on licenses but I could not find what I was really looking for.
Thanks for any tips

Answer (score 0):

The temporary key (`XXX_temporaryKey.pfx`) is generated by Visual Studio for code signing. It expires in a year. While its expiration won't directly affect your add-ins' function, it will trigger security warnings. It's wise to use a valid, non-expired code signing certificate for better user trust.

The temporary key's expiration isn't tied to licensing; that's a separate consideration. To control software usage, implement a licensing mechanism.

Regarding the "Sign the ClickOnce manifests" option in Visual Studio, it's not relevant if you're using WiX for MSI installers instead of ClickOnce.

If your users trust your add-ins and you're okay with them seeing security warnings, you might continue using an expired key, but it's not recommended from a security standpoint.